# Issue with unity 3d build on Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

I'm coding a gamification application where the interactions with the end user is performed with microphone and webcam. I'm using a 2019 mac mini with unity 3D 2018.

During the coding session with the unity editor everything works fine, but when I build for deployment the application becomes too slow and freezes when it tries to access webcam and microphone.

I gave all permissions for using these devices.
The build-ed application works well with windows and android.

Why I cannot use Microphone with the deployed app on MacOS? 
The same code works good on other platform.

Below I publish the piece of code in which I use the microphone:

```
   public void onPointerDown()
   {
        mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start("", true, 30, 44100);
        mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.start = Time.time;
        mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.audioSource.loop = true;
        while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0))
        {

        }
    }

    public void onPointerUp()
    {
        Microphone.End("");
        mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.end = Time.time;
        StartCoroutine(mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.SendRequestToGoogle(mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.audioSource.clip, 0, (mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.end - mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.start)));
    }
```

Comment: Do you try to run the release software on MacOS or iOS?

Comment: I made a MacOs build and I tried to run on a Mac mini and on a MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
mSpeechToTextManagerGoogle.audioSource.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 30, 44100);
```